# How can I use Jetty to serve servlets without worrying about War file layouts?

Tags: java, maven, servlets, jetty, vaadin

I have a pre-existing Java application and I would like to expose a web UI using Vaadin.  I'm using Maven for dependency management.

The Vaadin documentation suggest using a war file layout, but I don't want to have to rearrange my codebase into the standard War format.

Is there a way that I can programmatically start a Jetty server and get it to serve up a servlet, without having to worry about war directory structures?

Some example code showing how to serve up a servlet from a main() method would be very helpful here.

Alternatively, if something other than Jetty would work better here, that would be good to know.

Comment: Have you checked on Spring Boot?

Comment: Spring seems very heavyweight for this.  This is just a small component of a pre-existing application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty straightforward to set up a simple HTTP server in-process with jetty:

```
final Server httpServer = new Server(18080);
httpServer.setHandler(new AbstractHandler() {

    @Override
    public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
                response.getWriter().write("This is the HTTP response");            
    }
});
httpServer.start();
```

Note that this is based on jetty 8.1.8. The code above does not use Servlets, but it is pretty easy to wire it to any framework you want.

If you really need a servlet (maybe you already have it ready) use Jetty's [ServletContextHandler](http://archive.eclipse.org/jetty/8.1.8.v20121106/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/servlet/ServletContextHandler.html) class instead of your own handler.